# Sorting items by date. And adding numbers from today

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is Model and View Model. I am using UserDefaults for saving data.

```
import Foundation


struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var int: Int
    var date = Date()
}

class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var ItemList = [Item] ()
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "ItemList"),
              let savedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data) else { ItemList = []; return }
        
        ItemList = savedItems
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(ItemList)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "ItemList")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

and this is the view. I am tryng too add new item and sort them by date. After that adding numbers on totalNumber. I tried .sorted() in ForEach but its not work for sort by date. and I try to create a func for adding numbers and that func is not work thoo.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var int = 0
    
    @AppStorage("TOTAL_NUMBER") var totalNumber = 0
    
    
    @StateObject var VM = ItemViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Name:")
                    TextField("Type Here...", text: $name)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Number:")
                    TextField("Type Here...", value: $int, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                }
                
                Button {
                    addItem()
                    VM.save()
                    name = ""
                    int = 0
                } label: {
                    Text ("ADD PERSON")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                List(VM.ItemList) { Item in
                    Text(Item.name)
                    Text("\(Item.int)")
                    Text("\(Item.date, format: .dateTime.day().month().year())")
                }
                
                Text("\(totalNumber)")
                    .padding()
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        VM.ItemList.append(Item(name: name, int: int))
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to sort `.sort{ $0.date < $1.date }`. And sort the data in the view model, not in the view.

Comment: Thank you i sorted list in the init() part and its work fine. And second part of my question how can i addition those numbers in the total number ? @vadian

Comment: What does *addition those numbers* mean?

Comment: I want to sum the numbers added on the same day. @vadian

Comment: Do you mean the sum of all `int` properties? Do it also in the view model. `filter` the array by `IsDateInToday` of `Calendar`, then `map` the items to their `int` property and sum up the array with `reduce`

Comment: let calendar = Calendar.current
        let todayDates = ItemList.filter({calendar.isDateInToday($0.date as Date)}) --- When i do that in init() part sort method is not working. I dont understand which part i should use in my code. @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please name variables always with starting lowercase letter for example

```
@Published var itemList = [Item] ()
@StateObject var vm = ItemViewModel()
```

To sort the items by date in the view model replace

```
itemList = savedItems
```

with

```
itemList = savedItems.sorted{ $0.date < $1.date }
```

To show the sum of all `int` properties of the *today items* add a `@Published var totalNumber` in the view model and a method to calculate the value. Call this method in `load` and `save`

```
class ItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var itemList = [Item] ()
    @Published var totalNumber = 0
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "ItemList"),
              let savedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data) else { itemList = []; return }
        
        itemList = savedItems.sorted{ $0.date < $1.date }
        calculateTotalNumber()
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(itemList)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "ItemList")
            calculateTotalNumber()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func calculateTotalNumber() {
        let todayItems = itemList.filter{ Calendar.current.isDateInToday($0.date) }
        totalNumber = todayItems.map(\.int).reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

In the view delete the `@AppStorage` line because the value is calculated on demand and replace

```
Text("\(totalNumber)")
```

with

```
 Text("\(vm.totalNumber)")
```

Comment: This is perfectly work Thank you. I will work on it to understand more clearly.

Comment: I realise when i add an item its firstly adding at bottom. After restart its sorted by date. Is there any way to fix this issue ? @vadian

Comment: Of course it's being displayed at the bottom because you **append** the item. You could sort the items at the end in `addItem` or **insert** the item at the proper index by finding the closest item.

Comment: itemList = savedItems.sorted{ $0.date < $1.date } i change that to itemList = savedItems.sorted{ $1.date < $0.date } and the newest add should be on top. Acctually its work fine. Just after i restart the app, its sorted by date and newest is on the top. I dont understand why its not sorted when i add first time. @Vadian

Comment: As I said you append the item that means you put at the end of the list. You have to add a line `vm .itemList.sort{ $0.date > $1.date }` in `addItem` after the `append` line. To sort the list in descending order just replace `<` with `>` in the closure.